# when compiling JOS get errors that is underfined reference to _udivdi3 though I already installing multilib?

Tags: operating-system

We don' know why that happens? I have tried two visions of lab but both of them can't work.

Comment: what command do you use to compile. what error can you see?

Comment: This needs more information to enable somebody to help.